# What happens next if the root cause of one rocket failure won't be identified?

Tags: launch, rockets, failure, engineering

Supposing that in a rocket failure engineers don't find what the root cause was, what will happen next?

In general if the root cause will never be fully understood is there a law, rule, or standard procedure in spaceflight that tells what to do next for moving forward and starting to operate again? If not and these are situations where the procedure depends by the case, then how will it be managed?

Comment: Many times the exact root cause of an incident is never known.  A fault tree is generated and all the branches are run down to closure if possible, but often it is not possible.  Any open branches (possible causes) will be addressed, so more than one fix could be applied. Sometimes this process is executed and all the answers are wrong (like the initial try of fixing the foam shedding problem after the Columbia accident, and then there was a giant chunk of foam shed on the next flight).

Comment: I see it looks that sometimes they choose in arbitrary way what to change even if it isn't proved what happened. You have described well and included a good exsmple. Maybe further info and more detailed would be a good answer, or your comment could serve as a good reference for someone else that has some other info.

Comment: How is this collection of six questions not a *textbook example* of a question which is "too broad" and requiring answers which are "opinion-based"? Somebody (anybody) tell me! (e.g. $N_{COULD}+N_{WOULD}=12$). I propose that an answer considered good by stackexchange metrics can't really exist, looking forward to seeing an attempt!

Comment: @uhoh the question is very clear and i am asking what procedures are followed in that case were the cause can't be identified. Don't look "could" or "would" those are more info or material that i am trying to help the answer. Those aren't the question, i can delete them all. This is only one question, if it has a standart procedure or not, and this is very clear.

Comment: I don't know why it is considered opinion based. It wasn't considered 2 months before and now it is considered. This question is based on facts not opinions. Does it have a standartd procedure or not. If there is a law, rule, or standart procedure that tells what to do next, then you write it. If it is not and we have those situations were the procedure depends by the case than write that it hasn't standard procedure and explain why it hasn't and why is decided to be like this. This is all, what makes this opinion based?

Comment: Organic Marble comment was a good start for the answer. But he hasn't explained explained completely.

Comment: I agree it is a VERY good and interesting question! In the stackexchange ecosystem good questions are sometimes closed because the nature of the answer requires speculation, such as [this one](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/19373/12102). So I'm asking the "question closing community" why your question doesn't require an answer that would be primarily opinion-based and would therefore be considered off-topic (no matter how interesting and important it is).

Comment: Maybe the question here is simply (roughly) "*Does anything like a 'standard procedure in spaceflight exist for moving forward after a disaster who's root cause was never fully understood? If so, has it ever been used?*" An answer to that has a more *yes/no + example* format, the kind of verifiable answer that stackexchange encourages. Obviously with so much upvoting people find this to be a good and interesting question, can you adjust it a bit so that it asks for primarily verifiable fact-based answers? Questions that are 'closed for adjustment' are often re-opened after they are adjusted.

Comment: @J.Young I didn't expand my comment into an answer because I agree that your question is too broad or opinion based. For example, no one can know what SpaceX will do in the future.  If you edit your question down to something like 'how have rocket accidents been investigated in the past and what happens if there is no clear root cause` then it could be answerable.

Comment: What disasters have not had their root cause determined? An example or two would be interesting, as the rocket failures I know of have been thoroughly examined and explained.

Answer (score 6):

Its hard to answer this in the "typical case" let alone the general case because it will depend upon the manufacturer and customer relationships. Failure review board terms of reference can quite broad and "simply" say that the board must determine the cause and prognosis without reference cost and schedule concerns.

One concept that often arises in commercial, and perhaps wider, circumstances is the "most probable root cause".  At this point Organic Marble's description is a good start:

> Many times the exact root cause of an incident is never known. A fault tree is generated and all the branches are run down to closure if possible, but often it is not possible. Any open branches (possible causes) will be addressed, so more than one fix could be applied. Sometimes this process is executed and all the answers are wrong (like the initial try of fixing the foam shedding problem after the Columbia accident, and then there was a giant chunk of foam shed on the next flight).

It is quite common in both satellite and launch failure analysis to see many branches of a fault tree given a "not credible" assessment and then to find several attributed to as either "credible" or "credible but unlikely".  It may well seem uncomfortable to the outsider but it is not impossible to see lot of money spent on producing evidence against every branch of a fault tree through ground tests and generation of a range of corrective actions and yet the failure review board has only narrowed the range of possibilities for the root cause.  Then the "most probable" root cause simply becomes a coin flip between a number of scenarios, all of which happen to be plausible but unlikely. It can be quite unsettling.

If anyone is wondering what I'm adding to this answer myself, it would be that I have taken part in plenty of failure review meetings at equipment/subsystem/system level (mainly for satellites) and I have come to the view that this is a far softer-edged and human process than many people are comfortable with.  Satellites and launch vehicles aren't naturally occurring phenomena, every failure comes down eventually a human failing in design or workmanship. Correspondingly every decision to go ahead with a design change also has to be a human made compromise.

Answer (score 0):

If no root cause for the failure is found it should be discussed what to do: another ground test, repeat the launch without any change, add more telemetry and repeat the launch or do more tests during manufacture and assembly of the rocket. The problem is what extra sensors for telemetry might help to identify the cause. Additional high speed cameras inside the rocket may help to understand what is going wrong. But even if the next starts are a full success the team does not know if the problem still exists.